# Is it possible that the “section” parameter in imap_fetchbody which contains “period(.)” is an “attachment (not inline image or inline file)” type?

Tags: php, imap

## **Summary**

I am trying to fetch all of the attachments' content by using `imap_fetchbody` function. Below is the description of the `imap_fetchbody` function according to the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php):

> string imap_fetchbody ( resource $imap_stream , int $msg_number , string $section [, int $options = 0 ] )
>
> Fetch of a particular section of the body of the specified messages. Body parts are not decoded by this function.

But I am wondering what kind of `$section` might an attachment be.

## **My observation**

As far as I have observed, the `$section` of an attachment won't contain any “period(.)” That is, the `$section` would be a mere “integer string” if you want to fetch the content of an attachment. However, I am not sure whether my observation is right or not.

## **Question**

Is it possible that the `$section` in `imap_fetchbody` will contain “period(.)”  if someone wants to fetch the content of an attachment? (not inline image or inline file)

Comment: Yes, any arrangement of parts is possible, as the MIME formatting is controlled by the sender.  It's unlikely though; however, in enough email, you'll see just about every weirdness you can think of.